# CIFeature: Is there only Face Detection? Can I add behaviour?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-image

I read the below in the Core Image guide:

The Core Image framework provides:

- Access to built-in image processing filters
- Feature detection capability
- Support for automatic image enhancement
- The ability to chain multiple filters together to create custom effects

I saw the API and found that Feature detection capability is implemented using CIFeature but as per the documentation CIFeature currently supports detecting only faces.

Can I implement other types of detection by extending the class? If not, is Apple planning to expose such API's in the future? For example, instead of detecting a face I would like to detect a pet or a TV within an image.

I have researched and I think the only approach left is to make use of opensource projects like OpenCV.

I would really appreciate if I can get more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point you to an open source project [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) . Using this framework you can write your own filter to detect features different from just faces. The framework embed already some filters to detect features.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean I can detect pet faces, or plants or a TV etc:                                           
I will check it out.

Comment: I mean that you can learn from the framework to achieve your goal. There is no precooked solution for what you want, but it's a good starting point in my opinion